# create shape file from csv file with python

Tags: python, csv, shapefile

I am working on a really big script right now where I have a csv file that I have removed rows and columns from, and edited the headers. I need to create one big shapefile for the entire csv file then create individual shape files for the units under one of the headers. I thougt the best way to do this would be to use `arcpy.MakeXyEventLayer()`, I saw in an `arcgis` sample script to then use `arcpy.GetCount()` for the output file of the xyEveveLayer, then `arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management()` and `arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_ conversion`, but when I run the script only my csv file is getting edited and there is no layer in the output file. Is there a step I am missing or should this be making my shape.

this is the few lines of code I have used after all of he csv file editing to do what is described above:

```
    outLyr = sys.arg[3] # shapefile layer output name
    XYLyr.newLyr(csvOut, lyrOutFile, spRef, sys.argv[4], sys.argv[5]) # x coordinate column; y coordinate column
    print arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrOutFile)
    csv2LYR.saveLYR(lyrOutFile, curDir)
```

Comment: You might try this question on http://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There's really not enough of your code here to see what the problem is, but I think you misunderstand what the tools you mentioned do. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management` does not save data to a shapefile or any other kind of featureclass.  It only creates a .lyr file, which points to a data source and renders it with saved symbology, etc.  You can use `arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion` to create the shapefile from the in-memory feature layer created with `arcpy.MakeXyEventLayer`. Help for that tool is [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000003m000000).